# How to Fix :"flask request.arg.get('language') funtions return NONE

Tags: flask, http-post, content-type, esp8266

When i try to send HTTPRequest from Esp8266 to Flask App,
İt returns **None**

Im sending

```
  http.POST("language=python");
```

to flask server.

How can I Get a value on my flask server?

This is my ESP8266 HTTPRequest code :

```
 void loop() {
   // wait for WiFi connection
   if ((WiFiMulti.run() == WL_CONNECTED)) {
     WiFiClient client;

     HTTPClient http;

     Serial.print("[HTTP] begin...\n");
     if (http.begin(client, "http://192.168.1.107:8090/query")) {  // HTTP


     http.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");      
     int httpCode = http.POST("language=python");
     String payload = http.getString();
     Serial.println(httpCode);   //Print HTTP return code
     Serial.println(payload);         



     http.end();
   } else {
     Serial.printf("[HTTP} Unable to connect\n");
   }
```

This is my flask code:

```
 from flask import Flask,render_template
 from flask import request

 app = Flask(__name__)

 @app.route('/query',methods=['GET','POST'])
 def helloHandler():
     language = request.get_data() #if key doesn't exist, returns None
     veri=request.args.get('language')

     print(request.get_data()) 
     print(veri)

     return '''<h1>The language value is: {}</h1>'''.format(veri)

 app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port= 8090)
```

And this is my Results when programs are running:

https://ibb.co/C5YZN59

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the underlying werkzeug request `data` method. It calls `get_data` which appears to be working for you:

```
@cached_property
def data(self):
    """
    Contains the incoming request data as string in case it came with
    a mimetype Werkzeug does not handle.
    """

    if self.disable_data_descriptor:
        raise AttributeError("data descriptor is disabled")
    # XXX: this should eventually be deprecated.
    # We trigger form data parsing first which means that the descriptor
    # will not cache the data that would otherwise be .form or .files
    # data.  This restores the behavior that was there in Werkzeug
    # before 0.9.  New code should use :meth:`get_data` explicitly as
    # this will make behavior explicit.
    return self.get_data(parse_form_data=True)
```